# Number of groups on a finite set?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be the size of a finite set $A$. There are $n^{n^2}$ binary operations on that set, i.e. maps $A\times A\to A$.

My question is how many of them actually define a group and how does one even begin to answer a question like this.

I don't have any clear starting point in mind as the question is very "broad" and I think the answer may heavily depend on the size of the given set. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000001

Comment: Are you considering these groups unique up to isomorphism?  Or are you considering a group where $1$ is the identity different than a group where $2$ is the identity for instance?

Comment: @JMoravitz Of course up to isomorphism.

Comment: "*of course*" yet you refer to the $n^{n^2}$ binary operations.  If you were looking for some idea of what ratio of them were group operations, the number unique up to isomorphism would not be enough information to answer that.

Comment: OEIS gives [this](http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n). That should be your first stop each time you ask "How many ... are there of size $n$?

Comment: Given any finite group $G$ with $n$ elements, the number of possible groups isomorphic to $G$ with the same underlying set as $G$ is $n!$ divided by the number of automorphisms of $G$. In case of a cyclic group of order $n$, that would be $n!/\varphi({n})$.